# Network diagnostics for ZeroMQ Example

Tags: c, networking, tcp, zeromq

I am trying to implement ZeroMQ to get an application on a Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian Stretch) to communicate with an application on a separate machine (in this case Windows 7 64bit OS) linked by a wired or WLAN connection.

I have compiled ZeroMQ with the C library interface on both machines (using Cygwin on Windows) and the Hello World example (which I modified slightly to print the pointer values to assure me that the functions were 'working'). Both machines are connected (in this case via a wired Ethernet link and a router) and the connection is good (I link to RPi from PC via Xrdp or SSH OK).

The problem I have is that the client/server ZeroMQ programs don't appear to be 'seeing' each other even though they do appear to work and my question is: What are the first steps I should take to investigate why this is happening? Are there any commandline or GUI tools that can help me find out what's causing the blockage? (like port activity monitors or something?).

I know very little about networking so consider me a novice in all things sockety/servicey in your reply. The source code on the RPi (server) is:

```
// ZeroMQ Test Server
// Compile with
// gcc -o zserver zserver.c -lzmq

#include <zmq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main (void)
{
    void *context=NULL,*responder=NULL;
    int rc=1;

    //  Socket to talk to clients
    context = zmq_ctx_new ();
printf("Context pointer = %p\n",context);
    responder = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
printf("Responder pointer = %p\n",responder);
    rc = zmq_bind (responder, "tcp://*:5555");
printf("rc = %d\n",rc);

    assert (rc == 0);

    while (1) {
        char buffer [10];
        zmq_recv (responder, buffer, 10, 0);
        printf ("Received Hello\n");
        sleep (1);          //  Do some 'work'
        zmq_send (responder, "World", 5, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The source code on the PC (Cygwin) client is:

```
// ZeroMQ Test Client
// Compile with:
// gcc -o zclient zclient.c -L/usr/local/lib -lzmq

#include <zmq.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void)
{
  void *context=NULL,*requester=NULL;

    printf ("Connecting to hello world server\n");
    context = zmq_ctx_new ();
printf("Context pointer = %p\n",context);
    requester = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
printf("Requester pointer = %p\n",requester);
    zmq_connect (requester, "tcp://localhost:5555");

    int request_nbr;
    for (request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 10; request_nbr++) {
        char buffer [10];
        printf ("Sending Hello %d\n", request_nbr);
        zmq_send (requester, "Hello", 5, 0);
        zmq_recv (requester, buffer, 10, 0);
        printf ("Received World %d\n", request_nbr);
    }
    zmq_close (requester);
    zmq_ctx_destroy (context);
    return 0;
}
```

On the RPi LXTerminal I run the server and get this:

```
Context pointer = 0xefe308
Responder pointer = 0xf00e08
rc = 0
```

and on the Cygwin Bash shell I run the client and get this:

```
Connecting to hello world server
Context pointer = 0x60005ab90
Requester pointer = 0x60005f890
Sending Hello 0
```

... and there they both hang - one listening, the other sending but neither responding to each other.
Any clue how to start investigating this would be appreciated.

Comment: You might try to run "tcpdump" on your raspi or "wireshark" on your windows host to trace the network communication

Comment: What does `zmq_connect` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `zmq_connect`, you must indicate the IP address of the raspberry (which have executed `zmq_bind`:

It should have been:

```
// on PC, remote ip is the raspberry one, the one you use for ssh for instance
rc = zmq_connect(requester, "tcp://<remote ip>:5555");
```

Comment: This simple thing solved the problem completely - the two machines are happily ZMQing to each other. Shows my networking ignorance. Thanks for everyones' speedy and helpful suggestions which have also given me additional things to think about and learn from.

Comment: @WildCat Glad to hear this. Do not forget to test the return of `zmq_connect`.

Comment: @Mathieu You may have noticed that on your own, the API-v4.2+-call to  `zmq_connect()` **will not report any error-state** in return value or via the `zmq_errno()` for having done and attempt to a blindly misdirected `.connect()` to an otherwise legally correct transport-class address:port target ( although that will not (***yet***) fully-complete an intended end-2-end ZeroMQ connection channel ). So just the testing of a return-code will advice nothing useful in this root-cause analysis of the unhappy corner-case situation here.

Answer (score 2):

> **Q** : *What are the first steps I should take to investigate why this is happening?*

A Line-of-Sight test as a **step zero** makes no sense here.
All `localhost`-placed interfaces are hard to not "see" one another.

Next, test as a **first step** call `{ .bind() | .connect() }`-methods using an explicit address like `tcp://127.0.0.1:56789` ( so as to avoid the expansion of both the `*`-wildcard and the `localhost`-symbolic name translations )

Always be ready to read/evaluate the API-provided `errno` that ZeroMQ keeps reporting about the last ZeroMQ API-operation resultin error-state.

Best read the ZeroMQ native API documentation, which is well maintained from version to version, so as to fully understand the comfort of API designed signaling/messaging meta-plane.

---

### Mea Culpa: the LoS is sure not to have been established by the O/P code:

- RPi `.bind()`-s on it's local I/F ( and cannot otherwise )
- PC **`.connect()`**-s **not** to that of RPi, but the PC's local I/F

- PC **`.connect( "tcp://<address_of_RPi>:5555" )` will make it** ( use the same IP-address as you use in Xrdp or SSH to connect to RPi or may read one explicitly from RPi CLI-terminal after `~$ ip address` and use that one for PC-side client code )

Two disjoint ZeroMQ `AccessPoint`-s have zero way how to communicate,once no transport-"wire" from A to B

```
// Zero MQ Test Server
// Compile with
// gcc -o zserver zserver.c -lzmq

#include <zmq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main (void)
{
    void *context=NULL,*responder=NULL;
    int rc=1;
    
    //  Socket to talk to clients
    context = zmq_ctx_new ();                  printf("Context pointer = %p\n",context);
    responder = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP); printf("Responder pointer = %p\n",responder);
    rc = zmq_bind (responder, "tcp://*:5555"); printf("rc = %d\n",rc);
/* ----------------------------------^^^^^^------------RPi interface-----------*/
    assert (rc == 0);

    while (1) {
        char buffer [10];
        zmq_recv (responder, buffer, 10, 0);   printf("Received Hello\n");
        sleep (1);                         //  Do some 'work'
        zmq_send (responder, "World", 5, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The source code on the PC (Cygwin) client is:

```
// ZeroMQ Test Client
// Compile with:
// gcc -o zclient zclient.c -L/usr/local/lib -lzmq

#include <zmq.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void)
{
    void *context=NULL,*requester=NULL;
                                               printf("Connecting to hello world server\n");
    context = zmq_ctx_new ();                  printf("Context pointer = %p\n",context);
    requester = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REQ); printf("Requester pointer = %p\n",requester);
    zmq_connect (requester, "tcp://localhost:5555");
/*---------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------PC-local-interface------*/
    int request_nbr;
    for (request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 10; request_nbr++) {
        char buffer [10];                      printf("Sending Hello %d\n", request_nbr);
        zmq_send (requester, "Hello", 5, 0);
        zmq_recv (requester, buffer, 10, 0);   printf("Received World %d\n", request_nbr);
    }
    zmq_close (requester);
    zmq_ctx_destroy (context);
    return 0;
}
```

---

### Epilogue :

The trouble reported in the O/P is actually masked and remains hidden from being detectable by the API. ZeroMQ permits one **AccessPoint** to have 0+ **transport-class**-connections simultaneously, given a proper syntax and other conditions are met.

A call to
**`zmq_connect( reguester, "tcp://<address-not-intended-but-correct>:<legal-port>" )`** will result in legally-fair state and none of the defined and documented cases of possible error-states would get reported, because none of all such cases did actually happen:

> **`EINVAL`**
> The endpoint supplied is invalid.
>
> **`EPROTONOSUPPORT`**
> The requested transport protocol is not supported.
>
> **`ENOCOMPATPROTO`**
> The requested transport protocol is not compatible with the socket type.
>
> **`ETERM`**
> The ØMQ context associated with the specified socket was terminated.
>
> **`ENOTSOCK`**
> The provided socket was invalid.
>
> **`EMTHREAD`**
> No I/O thread is available to accomplish the task.

---

**There are some chances to** *at least somehow*-**"detect"** the trouble would be to enforce another sort of exception/error, but deferred into the call of `{ zmq_recv() | zmq_recv() }` in their non-blocking form, where these may turn into reporting `EAGAIN` or might be `EFSM` for not having completed the end-to-end re-confirmed ZMTP-protocol handshaking ( no counterparty was and would never be met on the PC-localhost-port with remote RPi-server-side ). This requires also prior settings of `zmq_setsockopt( responder, ZMQ_IMMEDIATE, 1 )` and other configuration details.

Next one, in ZeroMQ v4.+, there is a chance to inspect a subset of AccessPoint's internally reported events, using an "inspection-socket" via a rather complex strategy of instantiating
`int zmq_socket_monitor (void *socket, char *endpoint, int events);` attached to the AccessPoint's internals via **`inproc://`** transport-class ~ here **`"inproc://myPCsocketAccessPOINT_monitor"`** like this:

```
rc = zmq_socket_monitor( responder,                               // AccessPoint to monitor
                        "inproc://myPCsocketAccessPOINT_monitor", // symbolinc name
                         ZMQ_ALL_EVENTS                           // scope of Events
                         );
```

Such created internal monitoring "inspection-socket" may next get `zmq_connect()`-ed to like:

```
void             *my_end_of_monitor_socket = zmq_socket ( context, ZMQ_PAIR );
rc = zmq_connect( my_end_of_monitor_socket,               // local-end PAIR-socket AccessPoint
                 "inproc://myPCsocketAccessPOINT_monitor" // symbolic name
                  );
```

and finally, we can use this to read a sequence of events (and act accordingly ):

```
int event = get_monitor_event( my_end_of_monitor_socket, NULL, NULL );
if (event == ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECT_DELAYED) { ...; }
if (event == ... ) { ...; }
```

using as a tool a trivialised `get_monitor_event()` like this, that handles some of the internal rules of reading and interpreting the multi-part messages that come as ordered from the instantiated "internal"-monitor attached to the AccessPoint:

```
// Read one event off the monitor socket; return value and address
// by reference, if not null, and event number by value. Returns -1
// in case of error.

static int
get_monitor_event ( void *monitor, int *value, char **address )
{
// First frame in message contains event number and value
   zmq_msg_t msg;
   zmq_msg_init (&msg);
   if (zmq_msg_recv (&msg, monitor, 0) == -1) return -1; // Interrupted, presumably
   assert (zmq_msg_more (&msg));

   uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *) zmq_msg_data (&msg);
   uint16_t event = *(uint16_t *) (data);

   if (value) *value = *(uint32_t *) (data + 2);

// Second frame in message contains event address
   zmq_msg_init (&msg);
   if (zmq_msg_recv (&msg, monitor, 0) == -1) return -1; // Interrupted, presumably
   assert (!zmq_msg_more (&msg));
   
   if (address) {
      uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *) zmq_msg_data (&msg);
      size_t size = zmq_msg_size (&msg);
      *address = (char *) malloc (size + 1);
      memcpy (*address, data, size);
      (*address)[size] = 0;
   }
   return event;
}
```

---

### What internal-API-events can be monitored ?

As of the state of v4.2 API, there is this set of "internal"-monitor(able) internal-API-events:

> **`ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECTED`**
> The socket has successfully connected to a remote peer. The event value is the file descriptor (FD) of the underlying network socket. Warning: there is no guarantee that the FD is still valid by the time your code receives this event.
>
> **`ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECT_DELAYED`**
> A connect request on the socket is pending. The event value is unspecified.
>
> **`ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECT_RETRIED`**
> A connect request failed, and is now being retried. The event value is the reconnect interval in milliseconds. Note that the reconnect interval is recalculated at each retry.
>
> **`ZMQ_EVENT_LISTENING`**
> The socket was successfully bound to a network interface. The event value is the FD of the underlying network socket. Warning: there is no guarantee that the FD is still valid by the time your code receives this event.
>
> **`ZMQ_EVENT_BIND_FAILED`**
> The socket could not bind to a given interface. The event value is the errno generated by the system bind call.
>
> **`ZMQ_EVENT_ACCEPTED`**
> The socket has accepted a connection from a remote peer. The event value is the FD of the underlying network socket. Warning: there is no guarantee that the FD is still valid by the time your code receives this event.
>
> **`ZMQ_EVENT_ACCEPT_FAILED`**
> The socket has rejected a connection from a remote peer. The event value is the errno generated by the accept call.
>
> **`ZMQ_EVENT_CLOSED`**
> The socket was closed. The event value is the FD of the (now closed) network socket.
>
> **`ZMQ_EVENT_CLOSE_FAILED`**
> The socket close failed. The event value is the errno returned by the system call. Note that this event occurs only on IPC transports.
>
> **`ZMQ_EVENT_DISCONNECTED`**
> The socket was disconnected unexpectedly. The event value is the FD of the underlying network socket. Warning: this socket will be closed.
>
> **`ZMQ_EVENT_MONITOR_STOPPED`**
> Monitoring on this socket ended.
>
> **`ZMQ_EVENT_HANDSHAKE_FAILED`**
> The ZMTP security mechanism handshake failed. The event value is unspecified.
>
>
> **NOTE:** in DRAFT state, not yet available in stable releases.
>
> **`ZMQ_EVENT_HANDSHAKE_SUCCEED`**

---

> **NOTE:** as new events are added, the catch-all value will start returning them. An application that relies on a strict and fixed sequence of events must not use **`ZMQ_EVENT_ALL`** in order to guarantee compatibility with future versions.
>
> Each event is sent as two frames. The first frame contains an event number (16 bits), and an event value (32 bits) that provides additional data according to the event number. The second frame contains a string that specifies the affected TCP or IPC endpoint.